# How to uncheck first two checkbox of a group of check box?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a list of checkboxes. Checkbox name is **CHKBOXPAYANYONE**. It has four checkboxes. I want to unchecked first two check box. I am getting the checkbox item by using `$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]")[0]` and `$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]")[1]` . So please suggest how to uncheck them.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to select the first 2 elements.

`.prop("checked",false)` will uncheck the checkbox.

```js
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]:lt(2)").prop("checked",false)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]").eq(0).prop("checked",false);
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]").eq(1).prop("checked",false);
```

OR

```
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]:eq(0)").prop("checked",false);
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]:eq(1)").prop("checked",false);
```

Or You can use the loop also. 
For more read the [:eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

And [How to uncheck the checkbox](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/).

Answer (score 1):

Supporting @Carsten Løvbo Andersen answer, you can also use `.checked` html property:

```js
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]")[0].checked = false;
$("input[name=CHKBOXPAYANYONE]")[1].checked = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
<input name="CHKBOXPAYANYONE" type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Comment: If your question is answered with any of the above answers then mark it as 'Answered'/Accept the answer so that it would be helpful for others to go for the right solution. .